# how to count total diff timestampt laravel in one table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

model

```
public function getDiffInHoursAttribute()
{
    if (!empty($this->created_at) && !empty($this->updated_at)) 
    {
      return $this->updated_at->diffInHours($this->created_at);
    }
}
```

view

```
<td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($form->diffInHours)->format('H:H') }}</td>
```

how to get total data montly with diff timestampts laravel with format hour with minutes

Comment: Hour:Minute `{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($form->diffInSeconds)->format('%H:%i') }}`

Answer (score 0):

In this case ->format('H:i') should work. Have a look at [Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)